# Twig show source code but not HTML

Tags: twig

I'm trying to run Twig (standalone, without Symfony 2) in a PHP project (Wamp) but it doesn't work : Twig shows the templates source code but does not execute the HTML. I don't find why. Here is my code :

index.php:

```
// DOCUMENT_ROOT (constant defined in a previous included file) : C:/Program Files/wamp/www/project
$sTwigPath = DOCUMENT_ROOT."/vendors/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php";

if (file_exists($sTwigPath)) {
    require($sTwigPath);

    Twig_Autoloader::register();
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(DOCUMENT_ROOT."/templates");
    $tpl = new Twig_Environment($loader, array("cache"=>false));

try {
    $oTemplate = $tpl->loadTemplate("home.html");
} catch (Twig_Error_Loader $e) {
    error_log("Twig library not found", 0);
    exit;
}    

$aRender = array();
$aRender["myVar"] = "Wouah! myVar is displayed here!";

echo $oTemplate->render($aRender);
```

home.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Home</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    {{myVar}}
 </body>
 </html>
```

I've no error (checked in PHP and apache logs).

Comment: curious, have you tried creating the Twig_Environment with the options `array('cache'=>false, 'debug' => true, 'auto_reload' => true)`?

Comment: what do you mean by ' does not execute the HTML'? Does the `{{ myvar }}` get replaced?

Comment: try at the very beginning of your template file: {% autoescape false %} 

at the very end use {% endautoescape %}


let us know what happens now